# How to add responsive class dynamically on django-ckeditor using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, django

I am making a news website using django and I am having trouble in rendering responsive images which are inserted in django-ckeditor at admin site of django.
Can anybody suggest me what might be the issue, following is my code:

**template html**

```
<div id="modal1" class="modal bottom-sheet">
<div class="modal-content">

  <h4 >{{article.title}}</h4>
 <div>
   <img  class=" center-align responsive-img" src="{{ article.thumbnail }}">
  <p class="articlebody">{{article.body|safe}}</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <a href="#!" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
</div>
</div>
```

**base.html**

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.articlebody img').each(function(){
            $(this).addClass('responsive-img');
           });
      });
   </script>>
```

ckeditor at django admin rendered this HTML:

```
<p><img alt="nike shoe" src="http://www.nikeblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Nike-VaporMax-Flyknit-NIGHT-4.jpg" style="float:left; height:563px; width:750px" /></p>
```

i just wanted to do this image responsive but my javascript code doest seems to work.could you read this?

I am trying to add the materializecss framework "responsive-img" class using jquery. But I don't see the effect on my template. The images inser``ted in cKeditor is still not responsive. Please help guys. I am new to web development.

Comment: Can you view the source of the resulting page and post the section wherein the images get rendered?

Comment: yes i can view it..even the JavaScript also ...but the image not responsive yet.  do u  care tohave a look to source code?

Comment: yes i can view it.

Comment: the post and images all are rendered on template   just the images inserted in  ckeditor is not responsive.

Comment: Paste that section here. Let's see it

Comment: let me paste the codes wait a sec